# How can i get perfect edge detection of document in IOS?

Tags: ios, opencv

First of all sorry if question was asked. I am working on an app that can detect the corner of a document. I am right now using **openCV** to detect edge. I have achieved this using openCV but I am not getting the perfect result.

I have also tried the [BradLarson GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) but I am able how to start with this.

My code that detect the corner of the document but not a perfect result.

```
   void find_squares(Mat& image, cv::vector<cv::vector<cv::Point>>&squares)
{
    // blur will enhance edge detection
    Mat blurred(image);
    //cv::resize(image, image, cvSize(0.25, 0.25));
    Mat gray0(blurred.size(), CV_8U), gray;

    //medianBlur(image, blurred, 9); //default 9;
    GaussianBlur(image, blurred, cvSize(9, 9), 2.0,2.0);

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

    // find squares in every color plane of the image
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        int ch[] = {c, 0};
        mixChannels(&blurred, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);

        // try several threshold levels
        const int threshold_level = 4;
        for (int l = 0; l < threshold_level; l++)
        {
            // Use Canny instead of zero threshold level!
            // Canny helps to catch squares with gradient shading
            if (l == 0)
            {
                Canny(gray0, gray, 10, 20, 3); //

                // Dilate helps to remove potential holes between edge segments
                dilate(gray, gray, Mat(), cv::Point(-1,-1));

            }
            else
            {
                gray = gray0 >= (l+1) * 255 / threshold_level;
            }

            // Find contours and store them in a list
            findContours(gray, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

            // Test contours
            vector<cv::Point> approx;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
            {
                // approximate contour with accuracy proportional
                // to the contour perimeter
                approxPolyDP(Mat(contours[i]), approx, arcLength(Mat(contours[i]), true)*0.02, true);

                // Note: absolute value of an area is used because
                // area may be positive or negative - in accordance with the
                // contour orientation
                if (approx.size() == 4 &&
                    fabs(contourArea(Mat(approx))) > 1000 &&
                    isContourConvex(Mat(approx)))
                {
                    double maxCosine = 0;

                    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        double cosine = fabs(angle(approx[j%4], approx[j-2], approx[j-1]));
                        maxCosine = MAX(maxCosine, cosine);
                    }

                    if (maxCosine < 0.3)
                        squares.push_back(approx);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1) is there any other library that can do this.

2) is there any problem in above code? Should I add some image processing before detection?

3) Can [BradLarson GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) do this? And if it can then are there sources of sample code for edge detection?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how the results of processing with this code is not satisfactory? You say you tried BradLarson GPUImage, but then you already have the code, no? Can you not execute it?

Comment: i have used the Tutorial for the [GPUimage](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49525238/GPUtutorial.zip) thats real time detecting edges

Comment: using openCV i am getting this reasult [My app Actual Detection image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69268185/Detected%20image.png) and [What i want image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69268185/Detect.png) please help

Comment: We are able to execute it but edge detection for documents is not so proper. It only detects when the page background is dark but results less frequently.

Comment: Hough transformation? How realtime do you need to be?

Comment: @user869123 that i am thinking that if i could make background different from the page then i could do this

Comment: Right now we just need proper edge detection rather than real time edge detection. Like some apps on store TinyScan or GeniusScan.

Comment: The result you get seems very far from what you want do achieve and the algorithm sounds right, so I guess you have a bug or a problem with parameters.

Can you post the countours image so we can see if perhaps there is a problem there?

Comment: @GilLevi thanks for reply here is my [countour image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69268185/Detected%20image.png) please check it out.

Comment: No, that the final result. Can you show the detected contours?

Comment: If your book has a consistent image, you would have better luck with Natural Feature Tracking (that's what the "put a 3D thing on our guide book!" gimmicks use). But for general, unknown images… Welcome to the world of computer vision! Canny is likely a mistake. Try a hough transform if the book will fill most of the image, then you might be able to reduce the problem to an optimisation: fitting a semi-constrained quadrilateral to 4 bright points in angle/distance space (technically you have 7 unknowns: position, rotation, scale).

Comment: also you almost certainly want to be doing this at half or quarter resolution for speed. No point fitting at full resolution; the errors in the method will dominate. You can always fine-tune it afterwards if you need pixel-perfect results.

Comment: @GilLevi sorry but i am not understanding what are you saying. here is [My code](https://github.com/mmackh/MAImagePickerController-of-InstaPDF) i have used this library that detect the corner of document. i think i have to change some parameter as Dave said.

Comment: I would be thankful if you could help me getting the proper edge detection on this as some other apps like TinyScan or GeniusScan

Comment: @user2706127, I think that perhaps you are getting too many contours since you don't keep only the strongest edges. We can know that only by looking at the contour that you get.

Comment: Hi, I am creating similar app and using the code you suggested. but faced similar problem have you solved it? Please help me if you have done this this will be great help. Thanx in advance.

Comment: user2706127 Did you ever find a way to do this using GPUImage?